# Can't access remote PC

Tags: windows-7

Remote computer responds to ping but I can't access the shared folders.

I turned off the firewall, changed the network type between work/home and still no luck.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried accessing the computer using its IP?

Comment: Also, there firewall on th remote machine may be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn on remote connections to the PC.
Go to control panel -> system and security -> system -> remote settings.
There you will find the option "allow remote connections to this computer" and you have to tick that.

Comment: it is already checked